# VoiceOver doesn't continuously read over strong or emphasis tags

Tags: ios, voiceover

I have some HTML in a UIWebView that contains strong/emphasis tags. I'd like to force VoiceOver to read continuously rather than pause mid sentence, because of a strong or emphasis tag. For example:

```
<div> This text reads continuously </div>
```

but,

```
<div> 
    This text will stop <strong>here</strong>, 
    and the rest of the sentence is considered a different block 
</div>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, I have noticed this too.  I do not believe Apple allows direct manipulation of VoiceOver, especially with HTML. I have been looking for some HTML code that could fix this, but nothing has turned up yet.

Comment: Well, we could provide alternate content. That would be one solution... Thanks for chiming in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about this behavior on previous versions of the OS, but when enumerating accessibility elements in a UIWebView on iOS 6.1, if I was doing normal exploration of the screen using touches the text would stop when the attributes changed.  However, if I selected the start of a paragraph and used 2-finger swipe down, VoiceOver would begin reading the content in a cohesive paragraph.

As a brief aside, I discovered the 2-finger swipe down gesture from http://axslab.com/articles/ios-voiceover-gestures-and-keyboard-commands.php, which has a comprehensive list of gestures available while using VoiceOver.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Yes I think this is good information and will accept this as an answer.

Comment: Link seems to be dead.